# Sonarqube 6.7.4:how to change the default landing page to /projects from /about

Tags: sonarqube

I tried to change the /sonarqube-6.7.4/web/js/app.xxx.js from
    window.location.pathname!==window.baseUrl+"/about"
to 
    window.location.pathname!==window.baseUrl+"/projects"
and I restart the service but there is nothing changed.
what should I do to redirect to /projects. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You land on Projects automatically once you're logged in.

If this is a real issue for you, then you could force authentication (**Administration > Security > Force user authentication**)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, in that file also can find a statement like

```
t.isLoggedIn?n.replace("/about")
```

change it to "/projects" may work.